# When did LTI systems become part of the EE curriculum?

Tags: lti-system

When did universities start teaching the mathematics of LTI systems ("Signals and Systems") as part of the standard curriculum for electrical engineering majors?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical design.

Comment: Also, a bit underdefined, isn't it? EE majors? Which country? Which type of university (Germany, for example, has kind of two to three kinds of university that has EE programs)? Pioneers in that direction, or broadly accepted? What's "standard curriculum", especially in a diverse educational country like the US? What would you define as "the mathematics of LTI systems"? Like, as we know it, based on Laplace/Fourier transforms, or more like system theory pioneers discovered and taught it, which probably was formally quite a bit different?

Comment: It was taught in my EE degree, back in 1975

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm not really surprised by that; I think we'll be more in the 1920s-1940s, to be honest – I mean, Nyquist clearly could build upon a rich set of differential equations 1938; but then again we might be in a discussion between courses that are "classical EE" or more "EE/comm tech" or "comm tech" or "information tech" or "control systems"; I'm not aware of how diverse the different EE-related programs were "back in the day"

Comment: @MarcusMüller Probably more to the point, when or how could EE courses soften down to not teach LTI systems? It's about as fundamental as arithmetic is to maths.

Comment: Just checked – the first EE course did not really contain control theory, just galvanism, electrical lightning, electrical machines; but that was 1883... pre-Hertzian-dipole-era...

Comment: @Neil_UK wouldn't have thought that, but your 1975's degree is about 90 years late: See my answer :)

Comment: in my experience 4 decades ago, there was the initial circuits course, where we learn KVL, KCL, node-voltage, loop-current, a little transient analysis, and phasors.  then we had two semesters of "Linear Electric Circuits" which was not as formalized as "Circuits and Systems" is now but had Laplace Transform and such.  (also had two-port analysis and similar.)  i don't think it was until the '80s and books like Oppenheim and Wilsky that it became as formalized in the EE curriculum.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson interesting! I'm currently thinking about the fully-fledged Laplace-based formalization of control systems as LTI; I know that in the German EE education, Otto Föllinger was *the* didactic milestone, and he took the chair of the freshly founded Institute for Control Systems within the Karlsruhe EE degree in 1965, and taught students right away

Comment: i consider Control Systems to be a **subsequent** course to LTI System Theory (the kinda course that [Oppenheim & Willsky](https://www.amazon.com/Signals-Systems-2nd-Alan-Oppenheim/dp/0138147574) covers).  **first** is *Signals and Systems* which is both formal and general and from that you can go into more specialization such as Electronics, Distributed Networks (transmission lines), Communications (and later Statistical Communications and/or Information Theory), Control Theory, DSP.  but the O&W book is not for Control systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So

> when did it become part of the standard curriculum

can only be defined by finding those who defined standard curriculum, and catching them the moment they establish that standard.

Well:

Welcome to Karlsruhe, home of the former Universität Karlsruhe (Technische Hochschule) [German, roughly: *University of Karlsruhe (Institute of Technology)*]; place where Heinrich Hertz proved the existence of the electromagnetic wave as propagating physical entity based on Maxwell's differential equations.

The first EE degree/course started winter semester 1885/86 ([homepage of the faculty](http://www.etit.kit.edu/1262.php)), and Hertz was teaching there right from the start; so, here's the first curriculum:

[image: Studienplan]

See "Dritter Kurs" (third course, i.e. third year/sixth semester)

Seeing that the poor students were exposed to Hertz's definitely physical/differential analysis focus for more than a year worth of courses, we can be pretty sure they learned *a lot* about systems that are linear, time invariant and overall pretty close to what we know about these systems nowadays.

Now, the shape in which Hertz handled Maxwell might not have been the same as it is today, and of course he couldn't rely on a rich history of control theory with description of optimal control strategies etc, but it's certain that these students received what would become part of the standard curriculum a couple years later at many universities, especially in the German-influenced room (which, arguably, was very influential in the world of late 19th/early 20th century electrical engineering, not to a small part due to Hertz's groundbreaking discoveries).

Now, having checked that the first EE course (which was founded just three years earlier, 1883) at TU Darmstadt (which is not *that* far away) didn't have that much theory on its curriculum and was more involved with very practical aspects such as electrical lightning and making electrical machines rotate at all, I think we might have traced this down.

Comment: Interesting... I think of "impulse response" as being synonymous with LTI systems analysis, and yet the Dirac Delta function was only first published in 1930.